# DBRestClient.h not found for CDEDropboxCloudFileSystem (ensembles framework)

Tags: ios, dropbox, ensembles

I'm trying to implement Dropbox syncing to my iOS app using the ensembles framework. I'm not using pods, so I manually added the ensembles iOS and DropboxSDK Xcode projects to the frameworks section of my project, and made sure all the buildphases etc are taken care of (following the [instructions](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles) on the ensembles github page). No problems so far, everything builds fine. But when I then add `CDEDropboxCloudFileSystem` to my project (see [here](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles#including-optional-cloud-services)), I get an error saying that `DBRestClient.h` cannot be found. I fixed it by replacing `#import DBRestClient.h` with `#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDKh.h>` in `CDEDropboxCloudFileSystem.h` and commenting out the two DropboxSDK related imports in `CDEDropboxCloudFileSystem.m`

Builds fine now, but is this the correct solution, or did I miss something with my setup?

(I tried adding the ensembles tag to this question, but I need a reputation of at least 1500 to do so)

Answer (score 2):

If it builds, your solution is probably fine.

I guess whether you can import the framework header or not depends on how you are linking. Sounds like you are somehow linking a Dropbox framework on iOS. Is that right?

That might be a new option Dropbox have added for iOS 8. Previously, on iOS, you basically linked with a static library, and then you don't have the  option.

Another way around the issue may be to add the path to the Dropbox headers folder to your header search path.

PS I also don't have the points to add an 'ensembles' tag :(

Comment: Yeah, I have imported the DB Core API framework in my project following the instructions on the Dropbox developer website. Unfortunately none of your suggestions worked, I keep getting the same error. So I will just change the import line, no problem.